# How to find all Python built-in private variables such as __file__, __name__

Tags: python, document, private, private-members, built-in

I want to know all Python built-in private variables such as `__file__`, `__name__`, and their purpose.

but I don't see the document of all Python built-in private variables in www.python.org.

I have know `dir` and `vars`.

So, how to find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden attributes are sometimes referred to as magic methods (for objects) and for reference, I would check out the [Python docs on the data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization), which are fairly comprehensive and likely cover all of the attributes you're looking to find.

After you've learned the *hidden* attributes, you may know what you want to get, but hidden attributes may vary by implementation, so to abstract that away, use the inspect module:

```
import inspect
```

To get a *lot* of information:

```
inspect.getmembers(inspect)
```

To get the file and a bit more information on a module:

```
>>> inspect.getfile(inspect)
'/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc'
>>> inspect.getmoduleinfo(inspect.getfile(inspect))
ModuleInfo(name='inspect', suffix='.pyc', mode='rb', module_type=2)
```

Answer (score 6):

What do you say about:

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'f']
>>> [ i for i in dir() if i.startswith("__") and i.endswith("__")]
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

You can define an auxiliary function:

```
>>> def getprivates(obj):
        return [i for i in dir(obj) if i.startswith("__") and i.endswith("__")]
```

and apply to any object reference even to `dir()` itself:

```
>>> getprivates(dir())
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Comment: He does say he knows dir.